# I have installed the docker version 19.03, while running the docker daemon,containers are getting deleted intermittent after few days

Tags: docker

My docker containers are getting removed intermittent after few days.

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-08-31 10:12:44 IST, end at Thu 2020-09-17 23:10:25 IST. --
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.538275526+05:30" level=info msg="Starting up"
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.539105284+05:30" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.544986324+05:30" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.545033917+05:30" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.545086917+05:30" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.545114012+05:30" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.548578610+05:30" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.548640183+05:30" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.548673867+05:30" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.548698658+05:30" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.842884585+05:30" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.944238578+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 31 11:31:02 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:02.985979893+05:30" level=warning msg="7e9847e8c2ccb1cb3690316d19b66136d8f9fd5c9c436969bc7b6303db345d30 cleanup: failed to unmount IPC: umount 
Aug 31 11:31:11 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:11.081963154+05:30" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 69a759dcb5b230c1020e53a89ef8887e7447ce3064f930a8a914324d800cedc4 (404f29278912116b3cd04a407fe57cf16538cc623b2a2faa4328ab0cdb59fcba)"

Aug 31 11:31:11 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:11.542843230+05:30" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 6711cd7b1ce0ede11e852ca3bd0114934d14e83292364c27ee5808cffa1062c4 87ea9779402a38ffacf62ce84fdbf7cc2cd8419c4d0cae22ddc8468072b7ea6c], retrying...."

Aug 31 11:31:11 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:11.804699526+05:30" level=error msg="getEndpointFromStore for eid 2cc1662e8f61a8b7c549754ddc92c0c6d59d03905719ec32be5b63bd7f0ea881 failed while trying to build sandbox for cleanup: could not find endpoint 2cc1662e8f61a8b7c549754ddc92c0c6d59d03905719ec32be5b63bd7f0ea881: []"

Aug 31 11:31:11 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:11.804739901+05:30" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 6c96e15d6989d7c27fd0a304aefc7bdc9bbae90335523ffbefb0fb6e0624afd0 (527c74012cd1d0447850ea3fe13670f11dd8d294758b470e8e6b21cd7ea46edd)"

Aug 31 11:31:11 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:11.804780951+05:30" level=warning msg="Failed deleting endpoint 2cc1662e8f61a8b7c549754ddc92c0c6d59d03905719ec32be5b63bd7f0ea881: failed to get endpoint from store during Delete: could not find endpoint 2cc1662e8f61a8b7c549754ddc92c0c6d59d03905719ec32be5b63bd7f0ea881: []\n"

Aug 31 11:31:12 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:12.049373612+05:30" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox a3ac3dd4ea15a633a27320da2cae2d39de808a96d0841a34271b657f10f51483 (38bf61d74d42fad07beef7f68e1eec34a2854a149d78c1008f454b02df1bf9c4)"

Aug 31 11:31:12 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:12.412946082+05:30" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 6711cd7b1ce0ede11e852ca3bd0114934d14e83292364c27ee5808cffa1062c4 b2f51b62ffe030ca537438ff0c547597c61428e3079a91f5c6b62e46fdbfe955], retrying...."

Aug 31 11:31:12 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:12.660895622+05:30" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox edd9206a3ac0e5cd0adb28d04bdc15d4ffb36446b3557cbc7e3621e40459d9f8 (3167d0b093703c12e6978d052022241fb4c9088eec12247e743ad5ef9845240d)"

Aug 31 11:31:13 SPK-X-0036 dockerd[6678]: time="2020-08-31T11:31:13.009080357+05:30" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 6711cd7b1ce0ede11e852ca3bd0114934d14e83292364c27ee5808cffa1062c4 946f45722e853160f4d194eb01916c566e9dba2b57e8b48a4265147e1707385a], retrying...."
```

Comment: Try to add more details: OS Version of Host OS type of container, Docker is installed on external disk, into corporate network, deployed into VM machines, without detailed info is hard to tell.

Comment: The log messages hint at using the `dockerd -H` option to make the Docker socket visible over the network; have you configured this, and if so, has someone found it and is using it to hijack your system?  Can you provide any relevant application source code or any other sort of [mcve]?